# How to send a 400/500/404 response error through springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@PutMapping("/createUser")
public String createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    User thisValue = repository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    if thisValue != null {
        sendResponseHeaders(400, -1); // wont work
        return "account exist";
    }
    sendResponseHeaders(200, -1); // wont work
    return "reached here";
}
```

com.sun.httpserver that I used before has a sendResponseheaders method and I cant find that on springboot. Is there anyway to accomplish this. Basically what I want it. If I send a json request body with a username that exist then a 400 response error should occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal controller:

```
@PutMapping("/createUser")
public ModelAndView createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("reached-here");
    User thisValue = repository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    if (thisValue != null) {
        model.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        model.setValueName("account-exist");
    }else{
        model.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return mv;
}
```

In a REST controller:

```
@PutMapping("/createUser")
public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    User thisValue = repository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    if (thisValue != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("account-exist", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }else{
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("reached here", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Like this.

```
@PutMapping("/createUser")
public ResponseEntity createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    User thisValue = repository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    if (thisValue != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

[More information](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-responseentity)

Comment: Then what? Like what is the method

Answer (score 1):

In addition to returning an explicit `ResponseEntity`, you can throw an exception (or allow an exception to escape) that is annotated at the class level with `@ResponseStatus`. The default Spring MVC configuration will intercept any exception coming out of a controller method and will return an HTTP 500 (general "server error") if it has no annotation or the specified status if it does.